# Can you re-enable ClearType on IE8 after using a filter?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, cleartype

Is there a way to re-enable ClearType after using a filter on Internet Explorer 8?

I have used a filter to create a gradient on IE8, and I know already that filters remove ClearType. Now font that is displayed in the gradient is fuzzy and hard to read on IE8.

Can I enable ClearType manually?

I have used a png image as a gradient for now, but it's not as flexible as the filter because IE8 doesn't allow the image to be stretched vertically without using a fixed position (I need to us an absolute position).

Any tips?

Comment: No, I don’t think there is a way to “enable” cleartype again. IE’s filters have several drawbacks, and therefor one should refrain from using them whenever possible. As for the stretching of the image, not sure what you mean about the difference between absolute and fixed positioning.

Comment: Can't you add an `<img>` inside a div and set the img to 0,0,100%,100% size?

Comment: Thanks for the info CBroe, I've just be trying to find a definitive answer.

It's a background image on a Navigation bar. The navigation bar has absolute positioning, and when I set height and width to 100%, it doesn't use the height and width of the container, but instead the height and width of the page. Apparently fixed positioning solves this, but the design prevents me from using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to enable ClearType after using a filter.

Filters should be avoided when possible due the limitations that they cause.